# Looptools options not available in addons in v3.0.1?

Tags: mesh, interface

How to use loops tools in 3.0.1?its not available in the addons section.
Its also not  appearing in the right click menu.

Anyone else facing this problem?

Comment: Don't have 3.0.1 on this machine now, but the addon is certainly available in 2.9.3 and 3.2.1. Search for 'loop' in Edit > Preferences > addons tab and it should find 'Mesh: LoopTools'. Check the checkbox and it should appear in Edit mode on the right-click menu and the sidebar 'Edit' tab.

Comment: Hi :). It's still there, under Comunnity addons ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have *Community* enabled in the addons tab, and not just *Official*.